# Where is ~/.config/MonoDevelop/ for MonoDevelop

Tags: macos, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm using Mac Snow Lepord and can't find "~/.config/MonoDevelop/" for the life of me. I have MonoDevelop (v2.2.2) up and running already, but when I tried to set up a template the IDE started having problems.

Namely, whenever I went to Monodevelop -> preferences-> Code Templates I would get an error saying "Argument cannont be null".

I tried removing MonoDevelop from my Mac and re-installing but that doesn't appear to fix this problem so I thought if I could find the above folder maybe I could remove that. However I am not sure how to find it. I put the address directly into Mac's "finder" search box and no results were returned.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Note: You are not going to see your .config directory in your user directory in finder unless you [show hidden files](https://superuser.com/questions/31580/show-hidden-files-on-os-x-except-ds-store).  You are going to have to get there via bash in the Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The tidle `~` would normaly expand to your home directory, e.g. `~/foo.txt` is `/path/to/your_directory/foo.txt`, depending on where 'home' is on any given system.

So, the file you are looking for is `/Users/your_username/.config/MonoDevelop/ ...`

Also, there are some shells / systems that simply do not support tidle expansion.

Comment: ~ expands to your home dir, this is true, but your home dir isn't necessarily /home/yourusername. For example, on OS X, it is usually /Users/yourshortusername

Comment: @Logan: Doh, edited. Thanks. I actually read "Mac" several times, first cup of coffee.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on a Mac, you'll actually have to go to ~/Library/Prefernces/MonoDevelop-2.x to do your install.

Comment: That will be including a tilde up front... Not the root library!